# Can I have multiple Exchange servers in the same Domain?

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I'm pretty sure that I know the answer to this, but is it possible to have two Exchange 2010 servers in the same domain that are not aware of each other? I want to have another Exchange server that is insulated from my main Exchange server without having to set up another DC, but I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Exchange is tied to Active Directory. You can't install Exchange separate from the AD Forest.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I'm pretty sure that if you did install another instance it would just look at it like it was another CAS node or something. Just wanted to see if anyone had any trick to get around this. Thanks.

Comment: @satori7 No, it's not possible.

Comment: One AD forest to one Exchange Org.